# Importing with package name breaking enum comparison in Python

Tags: python, import, enums, package

My friend and I are making chess AIs in Python, but we're running into a mysterious problem with enums. We encode the piece types in an enum like so:

Piece.py:

```
from enum import Enum

class PieceType(Enum):
    type_one = 1
    ...

def recognise_type(my_type):
    print("Passed ", my_type)

    if my_type is PieceType.type_one:
        print("Type One")
    else:
        print("Type not recognised")
```

We ask the AI for a piece (for promoting a pawn for instance) and call recognise_type:

ai.py:

```
import Piece

def get_promotion():
    return Piece.PieceType.type_one
```

bug.py:

```
import Piece
import ai

my_type = ai.get_promotion()
Piece.recognise_type(my_type)
```

So far so good; running bug.py outputs the following:

```
Passed PieceType.type_one
Type One
```

But here's the thing. The name of this package is 'Chess', but if in ai.py we change `import Piece` to `from Chess import Piece` (for instance if we want to put ai.py in a different package), then something goes wrong. Running bug.py now gives:

```
Passed PieceType.type_one
Type not recognised
```

What's happening here? Why does including the package name in the import statement break enum comparison?

Comment: Why are you using `is` for comparison, rather than `==`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: because you [can do that with enum values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as Python is concerned, you are importing a different module; you have `Piece` and you have `Chess.Piece`. Python will create *separate module objects* for these two modules, each with a separate enum class. The values on those classes are never going to test as equal.

If all your modules are part of the `Chess` package then you should *not* treat the files in that package as top-level modules. That means you should not add that directory to your Python path (explicitly or implictly by using a script in that directory).

Comment: Just so I understand, you're saying that we should use `Chess.` for _all_ of our imports, and that way we'll be using the same module object in all the files?

Comment: @Megdatronica: exactly. Or use `from . import Piece` to use relative imports. Only if `Chess/` is part of your Python path can you import the other modules in the package as if they are top-level packages anyway.